# Regular exp in c# and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

I have a regular expression in javascript for email validation.

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```

Right now, I have implemented a client side validation in project, but upon someone's suggestion I want to add additional server side validation.

This is what I found/modified in c#

```
 @"^([A-Za-z0-9]([-._\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([A-Za-z0-9][-\w]*[A-Za-z0-9]\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,9})";
```

I want it to work exactly as the javascript code.

Can anyone help me in modifying the code?

.

p.s: If this website is only for marking my question negative because it is not a hi-fi question(this i have experience in last 6 months and it was not the case 2-3 years back) then please let me know where I can go to get some basic help ?

Comment: If you want it to behave exactly the same, use exactly the same regex. There's nothing special that the C# engine doesn't support, just remember to wrap it in `@"...";` rather than `/.../;`

Comment: @Rawling what is the difference between `@"..."` and `/.../;`?

Comment: `/.../` is how JavaScript denotes a regex literal; `@"..."` is how C# denotes a string literal (without having to worry about escaping slashes), which you then build the `RegEx` from.

Comment: Note that there can be top-level domains (the last part of the address) of more than 4 characters (.travel, .museum). You could use a `{2,}` quantifier there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the regex to work exactly like in JavaScript, you can use it almost unchanged, just drop the delimiters:

```
@"^([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+@([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$"
```

(You don't need to escape the `@` or the dot (when it's inside a character class), by the way. This is true for .NET as well as JavaScript.)